# UIImagePickerController mediaTypes kUTTypeMovie causes small memory leak in NSCFNumber

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode-instruments

Xcode 4.0.2
iPhone4 iOS 4.3.5
CoreLocation and MobileCoreServices frameworks are implemented.
imported `MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h`

```
- (void) displayVideoPicker
{
    UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    ipc.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    ipc.videoMaximumDuration = 45.0f;
    ipc.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;
    ipc.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
    [ipc release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

Instruments is reporting small 16 Bytes leaks on `NSCFNumber`, possible Frame `FigRemote_CreatePropertyListFromBinaryPListData`:

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
NSCFNumber,8        128 Bytes   MediaToolbox FigRemote_CreatePropertyListFromBinaryPListData
```

If I remove this line the leak goes away:

```
ipc.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```

I've tried this and it didn't get rid of the leak.

```
NSArray *myMediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
ipc.mediaTypes = myMediaTypes;
[myMediaTypes release];
```

The leak occurs just after picking the video and returning to the initial view.  Any thoughts?

Comment: why are you casting the constant to a string? without looking at the docs..that seems like its unnecessary

Comment: oh i see..was thinking the constant might be a primitive, but its a CFStringRef...hmm...well its 16 bytes, its not going to matter honestly, and from where its happening it looks like an Apple bug when it creates a plist from a binary plist internally

Comment: @marshn Did any of the two answers help you solve your problem? Please select one of them as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a couple of leaks around the `UIImagePickerController` and this was one of them. Total leak was 208 bytes. I found that if the media types are specified using `CoreFoundation` C code, this leak goes away.

So the following code leaks:

```
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage, (NSString*)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```

Can be replaced by the following code which does not cause the same leak:

```
CFStringRef mTypes[2] = { kUTTypeImage, kUTTypeMovie };

CFArrayRef mTypesArray = CFArrayCreate(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), (const void**)mTypes, 2, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

imagePickerController.mediaTypes = (NSArray*)mTypesArray;

CFRelease(mTypesArray);
```

My theory is that the leaking statement is not providing the information that the final argument of the working code provides. `kCFTypeArrayCallBacks` provides the `CFArray` created with the information it needs to properly retain and release the objects it contains (using `CFRetain` and `CFRelease`). These objects it contains are `CFStringRefs..`. The leaking statement casts these `CFStringRefs` to `NSStrings` and I think the `NSArray` is using Objective-C standard retain and release messages on its objects.

This theory would seem to be bogus because `CFArray` and `NSArray` are toll-free bridged and it should "just work". I'm sticking with it for now though - it's the only significant difference between the two code snippets above that jumps out at me.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to be sure to include the `MobileCoreServices Framework` into your Xcode project, then `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>` which gives you access to the predefined media type constants such as `kUTTypeImage` and `KUTTypeMovie`.

Then, you need to know that `mediaType` *property* expects an *array*, even if it contains only one element.

The view controller you are putting this code in needs to be the delegate for these two: `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

Then you can put this code somewhere to have it be executed (like inside a button action):

```
UIImagePickerController *camera = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
camera.delegate = self;
camera.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, (NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
[self presentViewController:camera animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also, on line 4 of my code above where it says `camera.mediaTypes`, you could just easily do this as well:

```
camera.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
```

Comment: Code answers should have an accompanying explanation.  Please elaborate on how/why this fixes the issue.